# Electron Angular2 and aws-amplify

Tags: angular, electron, aws-amplify

I am having troubles getting electron, angular2 and aws-amplify (Auth) to work. Everything works in the browser but when I try to run my app in electron I get:

ERROR ReferenceError: Auth is not defined

I am using angular-cli and installed aws-amplify with npm

Does anyone have a clue how I solve this ?

Comment: I solved it by using Amplify.Auth.signIn instead of Auth.signIn works both in browser and electron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get Auth object then sign in.

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.Auth.signIn(...)
```

Or

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.signIn(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using Amplify.Auth.signIn instead of Auth.signIn works both in browser and electron

Answer (score 0):

If it happened that you put Auth in an async function here is what you need to do:

Change your function signature and add auth input, then supply Auth for that parameter, then use auth in your function:

```js
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

await this.handleLoginCallback(
    this.auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile(),
    this.auth2.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse(),
    Auth
);

public async handleLoginCallback(basicProfile, authResponse, auth): Promise<any> {
    const results  = await auth.federatedSignIn("google", { token: id_token, expires_at }, guser);
}
```